# Flutter how can i get data when open from url

Tags: flutter, dart

What I am doing is share something and i need to open it in app. Mean user share productID to other user on whats app, message or anything when other user click on it i need to console that productID.

I need to know is it possible or not ? OR any plugin which is doing same.

Answer (score 0):

there's a couple of ways to achieve this, depending on the data type, you may:

- serialise the data and share it using [share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) package
- use the [intent](https://pub.dev/packages/intent) package.
- use may also use [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) to launch specific apps like browser, sms , phone etc.